# How to handling error Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close with flutter cubit

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I want to send the scan data results in the form of arguments to the homescreen page, and then call pinch getUnit(param). I got a true response from the api that I got. But the data is not displayed because of an error. Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close.
Error :
[image]
Cubit :

```
 Future<void> getUnit({String? name})  async{
    emit(UnitFetch.loading());
    try {
      final res = await _meterService.getUnit(kode_unit: name);
        emit(UnitFetch.success(data: res));
    } catch (e, trace) {
      print(e);
      print(trace);
      emit(UnitFetch.error(msg: 'Gagal'));
    }
  }
```

State

```
class UnitFetch extends MeterState {
  final LoadStatus? load;
  final String? message;
  final UnitListDataModel? data;

  UnitFetch({this.load, this.message, this.data});

  UnitFetch.loading({
    String? msg,
  }) : this(load: LoadStatus.loading, message: msg);

  UnitFetch.success({
    String? msg,
    UnitListDataModel? data,
  }) : this(load: LoadStatus.success, message: msg, data: data);

  UnitFetch.error({required String msg})
      : this(load: LoadStatus.error, message: msg);
}
```

HomeScreen get data with argument

```
void _fetch() {
    if (qrText != '') {
      context.read<MeterCubit>().getUnit(name: qrText);
    } else {
      context.read<MeterCubit>().getUnitList();
    }
  }
```

HomeScreen :

```
BlocBuilder<MeterCubit, MeterState>(
                      buildWhen: (previouse, current) => current is UnitFetch,
                      builder: (context, state) {
                        if (state is UnitFetch) {
                          _lastMeter = state.data?.endMeter;
                          if (state.load == LoadStatus.loading) {
                            return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                color: ColorData.primary,
                              ),
                            );
                          } else if (state.data == null) {
                            return Text('Data Not Found');
                          }
                          return InputTextField(
                            title: "Kode Unit",
                            hint: "${state.data?.kodeUnit ?? ''}",
                            widget: SizedBox(),
                            controller: _lastMeterController,
                          );
                        }
                        return InputTextField(
                          title: "Kode Unit",
                          hint: "${_lastMeter ?? ''}",
                          widget: SizedBox(),
                          controller: _lastMeterController,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: bro, I suggest you attach the code not the image, let say because the problem is cubit it would be better if you add: State, Cubit, and the UI class you implemented the state management.